# Jackson 2.x. Field not recognized unless using @JsonProperty

Tags: jackson

`@JsonProperty("friends_count")
            long friends_count;`

Using this. My jackson mapper throws a fit unless I label it with the annotation. The JSON is labeled as "friend_count".

01-24 18:36:30.469: E//RequestRunner.java:134(8336): Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "friends_count" (class co.hinge.mobile.android.models.ProfileP

Here's the JSON:

`"network": {
            "stats": {
                "friends_count": 306
            },
            "bands": {
                "friend_band": 1
            }
        }`

Comment: Could you show your JSON? It looks like yoe have typo in the name of the property: `friends_count` not `friend_count`.

Comment: Thanks Michal, I edited my post. I double checked the language, everything looks ago. It works if I use the JsonProperty tag, but jackson doesn't find it otherwise. :/

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Could you also show me your POJO class? It will be really helpful.